# VBA copy button to copy text from textbox

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a copy button to copy the text i previously inserted in a textbox, all this in excell

Answer (score 8):

Consider you have a TextBox named `TextBox1` and a CommandButton named `CommandButton1`:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim MyData As New DataObject
    MyData.SetText TextBox1.Text
    MyData.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

After clicking CommandButton1, the text on TextBox1 is ready to be pasted in any proper place.